# How to print a nested list as a matrix in python while executing a program?

Tags: python-3.x

For example,if i have a list l as:

```
l = [[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]]
```

I want to print the list as:

```
[[1,0,0],
 [0,1,0],
 [0,0,1]]
```

Comment: Question: Print where? A file? An interactive shell? And do you have numpy?

Comment: Just print while executing the program in an interactive shell and no,I don't have numpy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could go minimalist:

```
>>> l = [[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]
>>> 
>>> print(*l, sep='\n')
[1, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 1]
>>>
```

The * in front of the `l` makes the contents of the list individual arguments to the `print()` function. As if we had said:

```
print([1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], sep='\n')
```